# Insert values into API request dynamically?

Tags: python-3.x

I have an API request I'm writing to query OpenWeatherMap's API to get weather data. I am using a city_id number to submit a request for a unique place in the world. A successful API query looks like this:

```
    r = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?APPID=333de4e909a5ffe9bfa46f0f89cad105&id=4456703&units=imperial')
```

The key part of this is 4456703, which is a unique city_ID

I want the user to choose a few cities, which then I'll look through a JSON file for the city_ID, then supply the city_ID to the API request.

I can add multiple city_ID's by hard coding. I can also add city_IDs as variables.  But what I can't figure out is if users choose a random number of cities (could be up to 20), how can I insert this into the API request.  I've tried adding lists and tuples via several iterations of something like...

```
#assume the user already chose 3 cities, city_ids are below
city_ids = [763942, 539671, 334596]

r = requests.get(f'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/groupAPPID=333de4e909a5ffe9bfa46f0f89cad105&id={city_ids}&units=imperial')
```

**Maybe a list is not the right data type to use?**

Successful code would look something like...

```
r = requests.get(f'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?APPID=333de4e909a5ffe9bfa46f0f89cad105&id={city_id1},{city_id2},{city_id3}&units=imperial')
```

Except, as I stated previously, the user could choose 3 cities or 10 so that part would have to be updated dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use some string methods and list comprehensions to append all the variables of a list to single string and format that to the API string as following:

```
city_ids_list = [763942, 539671, 334596]
city_ids_string = ','.join([str(city) for city in city_ids_list]) # Would output "763942,539671,334596"
r = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?APPID=333de4e909a5ffe9bfa46f0f89cad105&id={city_ids}&units=imperial'.format(city_ids=city_ids_string))
```

hope it helps,
good luck

Comment: This didn't work for me. I get a "bad api request" error message, which is the same result as what I was trying earlier.  
Just curious, did you try this yourself?

Comment: There was a "?" missing in the api url, I fixed it. Additionally, I've tested it with 3 different ids ("524901,703448,2643743") as the 3 you provided aren't real ids according to the site, and it worked fine.